# how can i retrieve data at a certain interval of the days

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to retrieve data at a certain interval of the days,

here are the code in my model:-

```
function get_expenditure($where=FALSE){

    $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('expenditure e')
        ->join('item t','e.registration_number=t.registration_number', 'left');
    if ($where) {
        $this->db->where($where);
    }
    $this->db->order_by("e.date_of_expenditure","Asc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array(); 
}
```

and here is my controller

```
$expenditures=$this->select_model->get_expenditure(array('e.date_of_expenditure'=>$date));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your column `date_of_expenditure` has type DATE then you can use `BETWEEN` MySQL keyword for finding rows in this interval. You just need first and last dates:

```
$expenditures = $this->select_model->get_expenditure('e.date_of_expenditure BETWEEN ' . $dateFrom  . ' AND ' . $dateTo);
```